# A custom UIToolbar with text shortcuts acts completely differently from the Keyboard with UIButtons and UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

I have what I believe will be a complicated situation to describe.

I have a `TableViewController` `(Event Entry)` that acts as an input functionality for users, where the users click on a `UITextField`, get taken to this `TableViewController` with a `UISearchBar` at the top and they can either select an existing name from the `TableView`, search for a name in the `UITableView` with the `UISearchBar`, or create a name by typing in letters in the `UISearchBar` for an entry that doesn't exist. If the event doesn't exist, they'll be prompted in the middle of the screen with a button where the text label is Create followed by the name the user enters. If the user adds in more letters, it gets appended to the title of the `UIButton`.

I have a `UIToolbar` that sits right above the Keyboard with 5 buttons entitled Wedding, Birthday, New Year, etc. It's there to help the user not have to type in those common words when adding a new event.

The data in the TableView is populated with `Core Data` with events that have been previously entered.

**Problem**
The situation I'm facing is the fact that the UIToolbar Button reacts in a different way to the keyboard. If I type in "Wedding" from the keyboard, it will either show me the results in the TableView that starts with Wedding, or it will show me a "Create" button in the middle of the screen to be able to create that entry. If I press Wedding on the UIToolbar, it does not filter the UITableView and does not offer me the ability to "Create" that event, though it does append the word "Wedding" to the UISearchBar at the top. It's only if I remove or add a character with the keyboard does it then register with the UITableView and Create button.

For example, I am creating an event called "John's Wedding" without the quotes. I type in "John's" in the `UISearchBar` and the "Create" `UIButton` shows up (because I do not have "John's" as an entry), so the Create button's title is now "Create John's ". If I press the `UIBarButtonItem` for Wedding on the `UIToolbar`, it gets appended to the end of the searchBar, but not to the end to the Create button.

So in the `UISearchBar`, I now have "John's Wedding" but the create button title has "Create John's".

If I remove a character with the backspace key from the `UISearchBar`, then the Create Button shows Wedding at the end of it.

What am I missing? It seems to be some sort of reloadData that needs to occur somewhere.

Here is the creation of the UIToolbar:

```
-(void)configureKeyboardToolbars
{
    UIToolbar *eventToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                          self.view.window.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];

    self.selectedKeyboardTheme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Keyboard"];
    if ([self.selectedKeyboardTheme isEqualToString:@"Dark"])
    {
        eventToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
        eventToolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        eventToolBar.translucent = YES;

    }
    else if ([self.selectedKeyboardTheme isEqualToString:@"Light"])
    {
        eventToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
        eventToolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        eventToolBar.translucent = YES;

    }

    eventToolBar.items =   @[ [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wedding"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Birthday"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anniversary"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Year"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],];

    // Assign the toolbar to the occasionTextField
    self.eventAddSearchBar.inputAccessoryView = eventToolBar;
}
```

This is the method that gets called when a barbuttonitem has been tapped:

```
-(IBAction)barButtonAddText:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender
{
    if (self.eventAddSearchBar.isFirstResponder)
    {
        NSString *insertedText = self.eventAddSearchBar.text;
        self.eventAddSearchBar.text = [insertedText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", sender.title];
        [self.eventAddSearchTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Here's the method that shows the Create Button. The Create button is created in the viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    self.eventAddSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    _autocompleteFetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self autocompleteFetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else
    {
        [self.eventAddSearchTableView reloadData];
        [self.createButton setHidden:_autocompleteFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];
        [self.createButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Create %@", self.eventAddSearchBar.text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        if (![self.eventAddSearchBar isFirstResponder])
        {
            self.shouldBeginEditing = NO;
            [self.eventAddSearchTableView reloadData];
            [self.eventAddSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
        }

    }
}
```

So the issue is, the UIToolbar BarButtonItems are not having any impact on anything to do with the UITableView. If I type in Wedding, it filters the results that start with Wedding. If I select Wedding from the UIToolbar, it doesn't filter the TableView. It also doesn't activate the "create" button.

I hope this makes sense. I'm sorry if it doesn't and I'd be happy to provide any further information with this, but any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Situation resolved.

I called `[self searchBar:self.eventAddSearchBar textDidChange:self.eventAddSearchBar.text];` from the method that gets called when a UIBarButtonItem was tapped.

```
-(IBAction)barButtonAddText:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender
{
    if (self.eventAddSearchBar.isFirstResponder)
    {
        NSString *insertedText = self.eventAddSearchBar.text;
        self.eventAddSearchBar.text = [insertedText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", sender.title];
        [self searchBar:self.eventAddSearchBar textDidChange:self.eventAddSearchBar.text];
    }
}
```